# Laravel 5.5 group middleware redirected you too many times

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to write a middleware for a route group to allow only users with `is_admin` being `1`, but when I access the route, with an user which is and admin, the error message shows up:

> **This page isn’t working**
>
> localhost redirected you too many times.

This is my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if ($request->user()->is_admin === 1) {
    return redirect('/cms');
  }

  return redirect('/contacts');
}
```

I created a 'cms' key in `$middlewareGroups` located in `Kernel.php`:

```
'cms' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
]
```

And assigned it to my route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cms'], function() {
  Route::get('/cms', 'CmsController@index')->name('cms');
});
```

Accessing `/contacts` works fine, but accessing `/cms` will result in the error above.

Comment: You're saying.. if /cms then redirect to /cms, which re-runs the middleware which will redirect to /cms etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is this:
Your route directs you to the middleware. Upon finding that the user is indeed an admin, you use a redirect. As this redirect is through a url, it will use the route, which again uses the middleware.
Effectively, you have created an infinite loop.
What I assume you want to do is to simply continue to what the route points to after the check, like so:

```
return $next($request);
```

Comment: Your solution helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you saved me man.

To rephrase what you said in simple terms:

`The route which your middleware is redirecting to upon failure of some condition. That Route should be excluded from the middleware.`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want to check if the user is admin, and if yes, allow them to the route 'cms'. in that case, you shouldn't use redirect, but simply return true.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if ($request->user()->is_admin === 1) {
    return true;
  }

  return redirect('/contacts');
}
```